# Expected matching number

Tags: expectation

I have this question:
Let's say we have $n$ students sitting in $n$ seats,
Now we get the students out of the seats and randomly assign them to the $n$ seats, what is the expected students sitting in their original seats?

For example, with $2$ students, the expected student would be $1$. 
As we have student $1$ in slot $1$, student $2$ in slot $2$,

we have $1/2$ chance of $\{1,2\}$ and $1/2$ chance of $\{2,1\}$
With that, the expected matched students would be $1/2 \cdot 2 + 1/2 \cdot 0 = 1$.

Comment: I'm not sure this is as simple as it seems - find number of ways in which two children of the $n$ can be in wrong place, then do for three, four and so on. Then find the average. Finding number of ways in which $k$ children of $k$ can be in wrong place is also not an easy problem, so $k$ of $n$ is even more tricky. I am waiting for an answer, too.

Comment: The process if called [derangement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) and this expectation can be computed using [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rencontres_numbers).
Wish somebody simplifies the whole thing :D

Answer (score 1):

Let $X_i=1$ if student $i$ is sitting in her original seat, and let $X_i=0$ otherwise. Then the number $Y$ of students sitting in their original seats is given by $Y=X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n$.

By the linearity of expectation, we have $E(Y)=E(X_1)+E(X_2)+\cdots +E(X_n)$.

We have $E(X_i)=\frac{1}{n}$,  so $E(Y)=1$.

Comment: Why is E(Xi) = 1/n?

Comment: The random variable $X_i$ takes on only values $1$ or $0$. The probability that $X_i=1$ is $\frac{1}{n}$. so $E(X_i)=1\cdot \frac{1}{n}+0\cdot\frac{n-1}{n}$, which is $\frac{1}{n}$.